# I want to quit PhD after 4 months. Should I?

Tags: phd, research-process, graduate-school, professorship, early-career

I am a first year PhD student. I am doing it from an institute in a remote part of the world where the temperature is -10 degrees most time of the year. I took this opportunity after doing my Masters in Europe and I was really happy with the time I spent during my masters thesis research and really liked my research and came up with good results and very good grades. Now, I have taken this scholarship position but I am already in dark. As said, this institute is in a very small town. I can't speak the language of local people. I can't go out for a walk because its too cold.

I don't think that the project is difficult. In fact it is easier for me. But my daily life is not perfect because to read a research paper or write an article I need a fresh and happy mind, which in this city and cold temperature is not possible. I have money just for food and living and no more for even traveling to another city.

Can someone please tell me if I should leave this program?

Comment: We can't make life decisions for you.

Comment: It is your decision to make, do not let anyone or anything change your future. However, doing groundbreaking research in Alaska on million year soil would be fun, no matter the cold.

Comment: change as soon as possible, PhD without social life and conection is hell

Comment: Thanks for the comment dear. You understand my situation correctly. Yes, I am leaving it and without having any other option in hand. It is that much worst situation.

Comment: @SSimon, I disagree. There are many excellent PhD students that succeeded without social life and connections. Of course, it's not for everyone. It depends on the personality of the student.

Comment: can you give one for example @Dilworth ? Not in life sciences!!! It is academic suicide, unless if you are not in top tier universities

Comment: @SSimon, there are so many. But I dare not mention their names. (When I said connections I meant non-academic ones of course, since the OP is not concerned with his academic circle of connections, but with his friendship and social life---at least this is what I understood).

Comment: @Dilworth there are many example of phd students studying in cold, foreign institute?

Comment: @SSimon. No. We are talking about the veracity of your statement: "change as soon as possible, PhD without social life and conection is hell". It has no mention of cold or foreign institutes.

Comment: @Dilworth I was referring there to your nonsense that there are students that can make it isolated. Really? how many percent and in what field? Minority in range of statistical mistake.

Comment: As I said earlier, if you're talking about social isolation (not an academic one), I would certainly argue that many very successful academics (predominantly in theoretical exact sciences, e.g. mathematics) have been isolated throughout their PhD study. (And please refrain from rude speech next time.)

Comment: @SSimon Why do you think that social isolation's such a barrier to making it through a Ph.D. program?

Comment: @ChemicalEngineer bcs if you not share ideas with people, how do you expect to develop connections and wide your reserch network without connecting to people?

Comment: @SSimon Agreed that social isolation is a barrier to socialization/networking.  How's that connect to Ph.D. program completion though?

Comment: @ChemicalEngineer completion without anything else, is lost time, you cannot find job only with publications.

Answer (score 7):

It's impossible to advise you what to do. But I would consider to give it more time, e.g., a year, before quitting. You may still be effected psychologically by the change of place, weather, geography and location; you are still not adjusted to the new place. So you feel anxious and perhaps panic. But it may not be a good strategy to haphazardly decide on quitting the PhD while in this position. So I would advise you to wait more time and see if you adjust to your place and perhaps start enjoying your project.

(Also, PhD is never easy, and so mild depression while completing a phd is quite common.)

Comment: Thank You for the advice as it seems more logical. You used the correct word panic for my situation. In a comment before there came Alaska so exactly its a similar story. Today was the most difficult day of my life. So much depression. I don't want to discourage PhDs but I am concerned with my social life here. Me and my roommates call it a prison. I can take this pain if I am earning 5000 Dollars on an Oil rig far from world but only for food and living, No. I think I am going to do something wrong in my career but I am leaving it.